# Using PHP and xPath to extract clean table of text

Tags: php, xpath

I am using the below code to extract values from an HTML file. The code returns a block of text. I want to know how to improve the code and extract elements of this block of code into a clean table.

File:

```
<div class=class1>
    <a href="">txt1</a>
            <div class=lvl2>
                    <p>hello1</p>
            </div>
    <a href="">txt2</a>
            <div class=lvl2>
                    <p>hello2</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('file.htm');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$list = $xpath->evaluate("//div[contains(@class, 'class1')]");

foreach ($list as $element)
    {
      echo '<p>' . $element->nodeValue . PHP_EOL . '</p>';
    }
```

Desired output:

```
 txt1 | hello1
 txt2 | hello2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you could do it this way if you wanted to make sure you were outputting each table separately.  It assumes ordering is maintained, which I don't think is always guaranteed with XML / XPath, but in practice it usually is with most implementations:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('file.htm');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$list = $xpath->evaluate("//div[contains(@class, 'class1')]");

foreach ($list as $element)
{
    $column1 = $xpath->query("//a", $element);
    $column2 = $xpath->query("//div/p", $element);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $column1->length; $i++) {
        echo $column1->item($i)->nodeValue . ' | ' . $column2->item($i)->nodeValue .  PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I've removed the `@` error suppression from the `loadHTMLFile` method - I don't think you want to use that because if this fails you will get errors later on anyway, and leaving it out will make the cause of your problem more explicit.

Amended: here's another way you could structure the loop if you don't want to iterate separately over both columns.  It may still fail though, if the numbers of rows in each column don't match in the html:

```
foreach ($list as $element)
{
    $column1 = $xpath->query("//a", $element);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $column1->length; $i++) {
        $field1 = $column1->item($i);
        $field2 = $xpath->query("following-sibling::div", $field1)->item(0);

        echo $field1->nodeValue . ' | ' . trim($field2->nodeValue) .  PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < $column1->length; $i++) {` <-- This is causing an error for some values in column2. Is there a better way to loop through the values?

Comment: What error are you getting? It worked when I tried it on your example html above. It might fail if some of your column2 values are missing from the html, or if they are in a different format, in which case you'll need to put in some extra error checking. The problem is that the rows are not enforced in the structure of your html, so you have to loop through the columns separately and assume they are the same length, or else check in your code and decide what you want to do if they're not.

Comment: Or use a combination of this approach and my other answer. Loop through the `a` elements as above, but then get the next element for each one instead of looping over column 2.  You might want to check if it has a nodeName of 'div' and ignore it if it doesn't.  Bear in mind that there might be an empty text node after the `a` and before the `div` - which is why my example checks that the nodeType is XML_ELEMENT_NODE.

Comment: The nodes are not empty or a different format. I can fix the problem by change `$column1` to `$column2`. I will try amending the combination of the loop as I think the approach works in principle.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include another way of doing this.  I hope one of these works for you.  Would appreciate an up vote and/or mark as correct if it does!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('file.htm');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$list = $xpath->evaluate("//div[contains(@class, 'class1')]/a");

foreach ($list as $element)
{
    $nextElement = $element->nextSibling;
    while ($nextElement->nodeType != XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
        $nextElement = $nextElement->nextSibling;
    }

    echo $element->nodeValue . ' | ' . trim($nextElement->nodeValue) .  PHP_EOL;
}
```

I wasn't quite sure why you wanted `<p>` as well as `PHP_EOL`, so I left those out, but you can put them back in where you need them.